# Is the use of parameter[] the cause of this issue or is it a backend issue?

Tags: python, debugging, jinja2

I'm very new to Jinja and came across some code that I need to deal with in Leanplum.

I see a line of code that says `{% set totalDays = parameter['totalDays'] %}`.  I'm supposed to grab values from the backend.

But when I use that variable in html via `<p>{{totalDays}}</p>`, it returns `##ParametersRequired##`.

Is this a backend issue or is it the way the code's written?  I'm guessing it's the use of `parameter[]` that's causing this but I could be wrong.

```
{% set totalDays = parameter['totalDays'] %}
{% set totalPlayers = parameter['totalPlayers'] %}

<div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 25px; text-align: center;">
    <img src="https://image/images/vip/xaway/xaway-top.png" height="80%" width="80%" />
</div>
<div align="center" class="tk-museo-sans" style="color: white; font-size: 36px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;" text-transform: uppercase;">
    <font class="num-installs" color="#ffffff">{{totalDays}}</font>
    <br>
</div>
<div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 5px; text-align: center;">
    <img src="https://image/images/vip/xaway/xaway-bottom-long.png" class="xaway-bottom" height="70%" width="65%" />
</div>
<div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;">
    <img src="https://image/images/vip/xaway/xaway-vip-btn-install-now.png" height="50%" width="50%" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hey there. Please provide more [context](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with the template you're rendering and the code that invokes `render_template` including the values of the parameters

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh Hey!  `render_template` isn't being used anywhere in the block of code I'm dealing with.  Is there anything else I can possibly provide you?

Comment: How are you making use of the template?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh I've included the whole bock of code I'm dealing with

Comment: Assuming that this html file is called, say, `hello.html`, how are you invoking it?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh I'm not sure anything about a template.  I'm doing all of this in Leanplum.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know about leanplum. That said, please tag your question with `leanplum` and add that detail to the question.

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh This code's written in the `Text value` section in Leanplum.  I believe there isn't any invocation going on.

Comment: Let's try to take a few steps back to try and understand how you think this works. What kind of code do you think you have posted? Why do you expect jinja to be relevant to your problem? What exactly do you *do with* the code that you posted, from start to finish? When you say "it returns `##ParametersRequired##`" what do you mean by "it"?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh Will do.  But to my earlier question, is `parameter[]` valid in Jinja?

Comment: In jijna world, it's valid as long as parameter behaves like a dictionary.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel My main question is how would I use values coming from the backend and set those variable as a variable in Jinja?

Comment: Okay! You used the word `backend`! Now we're getting somewhere, I think. Please show the *exact* steps you take in order to make "the backend" *do something with this code*. When you were first asked "How are you making use of the template?", that's what was meant.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel lol nice.  I actually have no access to the backend, it's not my side of the fence to step on at the shop I'm at.  They just told me I need to use the values they pass from the backend in my Jinja code which's what I'm trying to do but it isn't working, I'm getting the aforementioned `##ParametersRequired##` when in reality, it should return a number.  I'm wondering if it's how I'm using `parameter[]`.

Comment: "it's not my side of the fence to step on at the shop I'm at. They just told me I need to use the values they pass from the backend in my Jinja code" *How do you get values passed from the backend? Where is your Jinja code?* "I'm getting the aforementioned `##ParametersRequired##` when in reality, it should return a number" *How do you "get" that result? Where does it appear, and what do you have to do in order to make it appear?*

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's my question - how would I grab the values passed from backend?  The Jinja code I'm trying to use is `parameter=[]` (in an attempt to grab the values) which's what was already there from the beginning (before I touched the code) is obviously not working.  I get the value `##ParametersRequired##` which appears on the browser when trying to use `{{totalDays}}` in my html.

Comment: I'm trying really hard to explain myself here and I don't understand where it's going wrong. Let's try this: pretend I am a new employee at your shop and I want to reproduce what you're seeing. I turn on my computer and I have a file on the desktop with the code that you posted in it. **What do I do now**, to get to the part where I open a web browser and see `##ParametersRequired##` on the resulting web page? Like, what exactly is your *interaction with* the backend?